# Get value of tag with class in HTML file

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$search = trim($_GET["q"]);
$url = "http://www.google.com/search?meta=&q=" . $search;
$gdymresult = file_get_contents($url);

if ($gdymresult != false) {
    if (preg_match_all("/class\\=spell\\>(.*?)\\<\\/a\\>/i", $gdymresult, $matches)) {
        $gdymresult = $matches[1][0];
    }
    else {
        // the spelling is correct
    }
}
else {
    // error downloading
}
```

And with the `preg_match_all`, I want to get the value of the i inside the spell class tag, which contains the suggested word with correct spelling. But this always returns false, so it means that `preg_match_all` has no occurrencies.

Comment: Obligatory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454?s=1|2.4259#1732454

Answer (score 0):

I get this result by using your code
[image]

so, i dont know what are you checking in your if else condition
Could you please be more clear?